# http get response for an Azure Website through a Console application in C#

Tags: c#, azure

I have a requirement where all I have to do is check if I am able to get a valid response from an azure website through a console application in C#. I have written the below code :

```
class ServerDBAvailability
{
    
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        WebSiteIsAvailable("https://somehostname.azurewebsites.net/");
        
    }
   public static bool WebSiteIsAvailable(string Url)
    {
        string Message = string.Empty;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);

        // Set the credentials to the current user account
        request.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        request.Method = "GET";
        

        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {
                // Do nothing; we're only testing to see if we can get the response
                //Console.WriteLine(response);
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            Message += ((Message.Length > 0) ? "\n" : "") + ex.Message;
        }

        return (Message.Length == 0);
    }
}
```

But when I run this code locally, its giving me an "`Unauthorised 401 error`" on this line --> `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()`. I am able to access the azure website through chrome.

I'm not able to understand why I am getting unauthorised error, even though I have access to this website. Please note that this is happening for site hosted on Azure only, for my other on prem sites this code is working fine.

Can someone help me out here?

Comment: The azure website is not running on a domain joined machine so `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials` is not going to work. How is your web application secured in Azure?

Comment: @Derek, thanks for the reply. My web application is secured via ssl. Is this what you are asking? If not, do let me know, so that I may provide more details

Comment: SSL is just encrypting the traffic. That's got nothing to do with authentication.

Comment: @mason, ok. So what do you think I should change in the above code to mitigate the error? Derek says its due to System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials. Any idea what else can I use in here?

Comment: It depends on how authentication is set up for your website in Azure. How do you authenticate to it? Does it have any auth at all?

Comment: You're getting a response, even if it's a 401. It proves that your web site is running. Do you want to be able to prove more than that? E.g. that you can authenticate yourself to it? Or do you want to go further and prove that you can get a success status in the 2xx range?

Comment: @sbridwell, yes I want to prove that am getting success status in 2xx range and am getting myself authenticated as well. Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: @mason, regarding the authentication part, its done via Azure AD. Any idea what changes I can make to my existing code to bypass that 401 error? Please do let me know.